# /u modifier for special characters does not work in regex

Tags: php, arrays, regex, binary

I am coding with special characters like `´` or `⋃` and for them I would need the /u modifier but it still does not work to display them. My code:

```
$input = array("⋃","⋃","a","⋃","h");

$input = implode($input);

$input = Normalizer::normalize($input); // unite binary code

$pattern = '/⋃{2}/u';

$replacement = '$0|';

$output = str_split(preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$input));
```

Comment: Are you saving pages with UTF8 encoding?

Comment: `str_split` is not multibyte safe. `str_split() will split into bytes, rather than characters when dealing with a multi-byte encoded string.` https://3v4l.org/ZvKSO `preg_replace` works as I'd expect.

Comment: What is the goal here? Add `|` after double Us, and then split into Unicode points?

Comment: @chris85 so is there an alternative for `str_split()` without splitting into bytes?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the goal is that after a specific pattern I want to insert an item into the array...until now this code was the most reliable one concerning my needs.

Comment: Good, then my answer is what you need.

Comment: You could do it without a regex, https://eval.in/692067.. or was this a simplified version of your patter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to tokenize a Unicode string into Unicode chars, I suggest to use `preg_` functions here.

```
$input = array("⋃","⋃","a","⋃","h");
$impl = implode($input);
$impl = preg_replace('/⋃{2}/u','$0|',$impl);
preg_match_all('~\X~u', $impl, $tokens);
print_r($tokens);
```

See [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/gSz34g).

First, `implode`, then `preg_replace`  to add a `|` after double `⋃`, and then use `preg_match_all` with `\X` pattern to match any Unicode grapheme.

Comment: Acc. to [pcre man page](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt), *`\X`* is *a Unicode extended grapheme cluster*. Look for *Extended grapheme clusters* on that page.

Comment: what sort of value is it afterwards? Because as an array you cannot operate neither with `$tokens` nor with `$impl`

Comment: why do I always get the error 1 if I operate with `$tokens`?

Comment: @ChrisWinterbottom You will need to provide more information (what error, how are you operating with it, etc.), also probably should be a new  question. Works for me as an array, https://eval.in/692147.

Comment: I think it is not related to the current question.

Comment: @chris85  new question is [asked] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027075/tokens-array-does-not-change-at-all).