# $tokens array does not change at all

Tags: php, arrays, token

If I want to operate with a `$tokens array` it always happens nothing. An example code:

```
$input = array("⋃","⋃","a","⋃","h");
$impl = implode($input);
$impl = preg_replace('/⋃{2}/u','$0|',$impl);
preg_match_all('~\X~u', $impl, $tokens);


$akzent = array("´");

$result = array_pop($tokens);

echo print_r($result);
```

Is it because `$tokens` is not a normal array?

Comment: 3rd param of preg_match_all defines it..(ooh @jeff, cheeky delete!)

Comment: What do you mean with nothing happens? Do you mean: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3771039/3933332 ?!

Comment: @Farkie yes....sorry, was a silly question. deleted it, realized it myself

Comment: What operation on `$tokens` isn't working?

Comment: @Winterbottom What are you trying to achieve exactly ? What is the expected output ?

Comment: The `$tokens` is an array that contains a subarray. You need `array_pop($tokens[0])`

Comment: `$tokens` before `array_pop($tokens)`: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => ⋃ [1] => ⋃ [2] => | [3] => a [4] => ⋃ [5] => h ) )  `;

`$tokens` after `array_pop($tokens)`: `Array ( )`

Comment: @ccs There was the mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$tokens` here is an array of arrays. That is why you need to access all the matches in the first subarray, `$tokens[0]`. Modify the part of the code like this:

```
preg_match_all('~\X~u', $impl, $matches);
$tokens = $matches[0];
$result = array_pop($tokens);
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/uWVUd8)

Comment: What do I have to do if I want to insert something with `array_splice`? I t does not work properly...

Comment: Not sure what you are doing with the code, [I can use `array_splice` with `$tokens`](http://ideone.com/D1STDO).

Comment: for example if I want to insert "ex" on position 1 `$ex = array("ex"); array_splice($ex,1,0, $tokens);`